# How to write a minimally working pyproject.toml file that can install packages?

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry, pyproject.toml, pep517

Pip supports the `pyproject.toml` file but so far all practical usage of the new schema requires a 3rd party tool that auto-generates these files (e.g., poetry and pip). Unlike `setup.py` which is already human-writeable, `pyproject.toml` is not (yet).

From [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects),

```
[build-system]
requires = [
  "setuptools >= 40.9.0",
  "wheel",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

However, this file does not include package dependencies (as outlined in PEP 621). Pip does support installing packages using `pyproject.toml` but nowhere does pep specify how to write package dependencies in `pyproject.toml` for the official build system `setuptools`.

**How do I write package dependencies in `pyproject.toml`?**

---

**Related StackOverflow Questions:**

- [How to init the pyproject.toml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229063/how-to-init-the-pyproject-toml-file)

  This question asks for a method to auto-generate `pyproject.toml`, my question differ because I ask for a human-written `pyproject.toml`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> my question differ because I ask for a human-written `pyproject.toml`

First, the `pyproject.toml` file is always "*human-writable*", it was designed to be written by humans first.

Then, it is important to know that in this context *setuptools* and *Poetry* take the role of what are called "[*build back-ends*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Build-Backend)", and there are many such build back-ends available today, *setuptools* and *Poetry* (technically *`poetry-core`*) are just two examples of them.

As of today, it seems like most (if not all) of the build back-ends I know of expect their configuration (including dependencies) to be written in [`pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/).

---

***`[project]`***

There is a standard specifying how a project's packaging metadata, including dependencies, should be laid out in the `pyproject.toml` file under a *`[project]`* table: "[*Declaring project metadata: the `[project]` table*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#declaring-project-metadata-the-project-table)".

Here is a list of build back-ends I know of that follow this *`[project]`* standard:

- [*`enscons`*](https://pypi.org/project/enscons/)
- [*`flit_core`*](https://pypi.org/project/flit_core/) (see [*`flit`*](https://pypi.org/project/flit/))
- [*`hatchling`*](https://pypi.org/project/hatchling/) (see [*`hatch`*](https://pypi.org/project/hatch/))
- [*`maturin`*](https://pypi.org/project/maturin/)
- [*`meson-python`*](https://pypi.org/project/meson-python/)
- [*`pdm-backend`*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm-backend/) (see [*`pdm`*](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/))
- [*`scikit-build-core`*](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-build-core/)
- [*`setuptools`*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) (experimental support since version `61.0.0`)
- [*`trampolim`*](https://pypi.org/project/trampolim/)
- [*`whey`*](https://pypi.org/project/whey/)

I have a [comparison table here](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging_tools_comparisons.html#build-back-ends).

For all *`[project]`*-compatible build back-ends, the dependencies should be written in the `pyproject.toml` file at the root of the project's source code directory like in the following example:

```
[project]
name = "Thing"
version = "1.2.3"
# ...
dependencies = [
    "SomeLibrary >= 2.2",
    "AnotherLibrary >= 4.5.6",
]
```

***References***:

- [*PyPA* specification "*Declaring project metadata*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/)
- [*PEP 621 – Storing project metadata in pyproject.toml*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)
- [*setuptools* documentation: "*Configuring setuptools using pyproject.toml files*"](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html)

---

***setuptools*** (before version `61.0.0`)

In *setuptools* before version `61.0.0` there is no support for writing the project's packaging metadata in `pyproject.toml`. You have to either write a `setup.cfg`, or a `setup.py`, or a combination of both.

My recommendation is to write as much as possible in [`setup.cfg`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html). Such a `setup.cfg` could look like this:

```ini
[metadata]
name = Thing
version = 1.2.3

[options]
install_requires =
    SomeLibrary >= 2.2
    AnotherLibrary >= 4.5.6
packages = find:
```

and in most cases the `setup.py` can be omitted completely or it can be as short as:

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```

References about the dependencies specifically:

- [*Dependencies Management in Setuptools*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html)
- [*PEP 508 – Dependency specification for Python Software Packages*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/)
- [*PEP 440 – Version Identification and Dependency Specification*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/)

Again, note that in most cases it is possible to omit the `setup.py` file entirely, one of the conditions is that the `setup.cfg` file and a `pyproject.toml` file are present and contain all the necessary information. Here is an example of `pyproject.toml` that works well for a *setuptools* build back-end:

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = [
    'setuptools',
]
```

---

***Poetry***

In *Poetry* everything is defined in `pyproject.toml`, but it uses *Poetry*-specific sections *`[tool.poetry]`* instead of the standardized *`[project]`* section. There are some [plans to add support for this standard in Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3332) in the future.

This file can be *hand-written*. As far as I can tell, there is no strict need to ever explicitly install poetry itself (commands such as `pip install` and `pip wheel` can get you far enough).

The `pyproject.toml` file can be as simple as:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = 'Thing'
version = '1.2.3'

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = '^3.6'
SomeLibrary = '>= 2.2'
AnotherLibrary >= '4.5.6'

[build-system]
requires = ['poetry-core~=1.0']
build-backend = 'poetry.core.masonry.api'
```

*References*:

- [*Poetry* documentation: "*The `pyproject.toml` file*"](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/)
- [*Poetry* documentation: "*Dependency specification*"](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/)

Comment: Some tools are starting to support it. But it is very young. I already mentioned `pdm` in my answer. Later on some other build back-ends have added support for PEP621 as well, but I do not recall which ones exactly, maybe look towards [_`flit`_](https://pypi.org/project/flit/), [_`trampolim`_](https://pypi.org/project/trampolim/), [_`enscons`_](https://pypi.org/project/enscons/), etc.

Comment: There is a package called [ppsetuptools](https://pypi.org/project/ppsetuptools/).

Comment: Python documentation has been updated with similar information https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/