# Is requirements.txt still needed when using pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-packaging, requirements.txt, pyproject.toml

Since mid 2022 it is now possible to get rid of `setup.py`, `setup.cfg` in favor of `pyproject.toml`. Editable installs work with recent versions of setuptools and pip and even the official [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) switched away from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml`.

However, documentation regarding `requirements.txt` seems to be have been also removed, and I wonder where to put the **pinned requirements** now?

As a refresher: It used to be common practice to put the dependencies (without version pinning) in `setup.py` avoiding issues when this package gets installed with other packages needing the same dependencies but with conflicting version requirements. For packaging libraries a `setup.py` was usually sufficient.

For deployments (i.e. non libraries) you usually also provided a `requirements.txt` with version-pinned dependencies. So you don't accidentally get the latest and greatest but the exact versions of dependencies that that package has been tested with.

So my question is, did anything change? Do you still put the pinned requirements in the `requirements.txt` when used together with `pyproject.toml`? Or is there an extra section
for that in `pyproject.toml`? Is there some documentation on that somewhere?

Comment: My understanding is that information that used to go in `setup.py` is now split between `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`.

Comment: I don't think the setup.cfg is much needed anymore. Maybe some 3rd party packages still insist on putting their config there, but regarding packaging, all the things from setup.cfg can be moved to pyproject.toml.

Comment: I vaguely remember earlier this year trying to move somethings from `setup.cfg` to `pyproejct.toml`, and `setuptools`  didn't recognize or find it. I agree that moving things is the *intent*, but I thought it was still a work-in-progress.

Comment: I opened a feature request for pip to support requirements in pyproject.toml: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12100

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting myself from [here](https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/issues/685#issuecomment-1321616748)

> My current assumption is: [...] you put your (mostly unpinned) dependencies to pyproject.toml instead of setup.py, so you library can be installed as a dependency of something else without causing much troubles because of issues resolving version constraints.

> On top of that, for "deployable applications" (for lack of a better term), you still want to maintain a separate requirements.txt with exact version pinning.

Which has been confirmed by a Python Packaging Authority (PyPA) member and clarification of PyPA's recommendations should be updated accordingly at some point.

Comment: Is your answer a *Yes* or a *No*?

Comment: The answer is yes, you still need a requirements.txt to pin versions for deployments.

Comment: thank you. this greatly solved my problem. just asking, is there any code template/example  for this hybrid style?

Answer (score 10):

> So my question is, did anything change? Do you still put the pinned requirements in the requirements.txt when used together with pyproject.toml? Or is there an extra section for that in pyproject.toml? Is there some documentation on that somewhere?

Nothing changed. Pinned dependencies do not belong in the project's packaging metadata, which means that pinned dependencies do not belong in the `dependencies` list of the `[project]` section of the `pyproject.toml` file. As of today there is no ***standardized*** section of `pyproject.toml` that I know of for pinned dependencies. This [document](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) even though quite outdated still applies in the spirit: "*abstract dependencies*" belong in the package metadata (for example in the `[project]` section of `pyproject.toml`) and "*concrete dependencies*" can be listed in a `requirements.txt` file if needed (or in any other file that serves a similar purpose like *Poetry*'s `poetry.lock`, or *Pipenv*'s `Pipfile.lock` to name only two of them, depending on the project's development workflow and tooling).

In short and simplified, the abstract dependencies are about the what should be installed, and the concrete dependencies are about the how to install (from which index, which version specifically, which build, which distribution, and so on).

Abstract dependencies are meant to be valid for anyone who installs your project (library). But the concrete dependencies will very likely vary from one user to another, or from one computer to another, they might even change over time. For example, some users might not have access to the same package indexes as others (*PyPI* is not available in some regions, some companies use private internal mirror repositories). Some dependencies need very specific builds that depend on the hardware available on the computer (PyTorch, for example).

Comment: Finally an answer that makes sense. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: What is an "abstract dependency"? You have said where these go, but not what they are or why we should even report them if there is a `requirements.txt` anyway.

Comment: @Mew, they are described in the [document](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) linked in my answer.

Comment: @sinoroc Only vaguely, and as you obviously know, it's recommended to summarise what's behind a link on StackOverflow, lest it disappear.

Comment: @Mew, yes you are right on this. I had already edited the answer to expand on this.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hadn't noticed. Could you expand on *"concrete dependencies will very likely change from one person to another, or from one computer to another"*? I'd think that concrete dependencies are version-pinned, no?

Comment: @Mew I added a few sentences.

Comment: It's clearer now (e.g. concrete would need the CUDA version for PyTorch), although I don't think I've ever seen dependencies so concrete that they say you need PyPI, but maybe that's just inherent to `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 7):

This is the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/) for `pyproject.toml`

> ...This file contains build system requirements and information, which are used by pip to build the package.

So this is not the correct place. Looking at the side bar we can see there is an entry for [`Requirements File Format`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) which is the "old" `requirements.txt` file

Answer (score 3):

**Context**

I found this SO question "**Is requirements.txt still needed when using pyproject.toml**" and have a **different use case** compared to the one described by the above question. Instead of opening an extra SO question with the same title, I decided to add this answer as kind of a "long comment", supporting users in similar situations.

In my use case **I do not install my code as a library** but use it as an **[application](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/meta/faq/#libraries-vs-applications)**.

It is possible to install dependencies from pyproject.toml by using `hatchling` as a `build-backend` and defining the dependencies in the sections `dependencies` and `[project.optional-dependencies]`.

Install the dependencies with

```
pip install .[dev]
```

Example for the corresponding sections in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = 'my_application_name'
version = '0.0.1'
requires-python = ">=3.11.0"

dependencies = [
    'cryptography==41.0.1',
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
lining = [
  'pylint==2.17.4'
]
formatting = [
  'black[d]==23.3.0'
]
dev = ['my_application_name[linting, formatting]']
```

**Related**:

https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/meta/faq/#libraries-vs-applications

https://peps.python.org/pep-0665/

https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/issues/685

https://peps.python.org/pep-0631/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75503961/2876079

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options

https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/1128

[How to write a minimally working pyproject.toml file that can install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150719/how-to-write-a-minimally-working-pyproject-toml-file-that-can-install-packages)

Comment: If you down-vote this answer, please let me know why and let me know of better solutions.

Comment: This answer is a bit all over the place. The point **b)** and **c)** seem quite irrelevant to the question. Regarding the **b)** point, a project should always have a `[build-system]`, if it is missing from the project, then it is a misbehaving project. Regarding **c)**, this is an issue with your linter. The directory name is perfectly fine, this is how it should be, it does not have to be snake case, your linter should not care about this name anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I do want to enforce snake_case naming convention in my python project. If you know how to disable/avoid the creation of the egg file in the src folder, please let me know. I guess I do neither need the build system nor the egg file in my use case.

Comment: Thinking about it, `*.egg-info` might be a thing specific to *setuptools*, you might be able to get rid of that directory by switching to a different build back-end. Not sure. -- Anyway in principle it is a build artifact that you can and should ignore. I doubt you can do anything about the way it is named.

Comment: That is good to know. For my use case it would be helpful, if the default build-backend would not be setuptools but a none build backend, where no artifacts are built but only the wanted dependencies are installed. (Both, specifying my requirements as dependencies for the build-system as well as for the project would be fine for me... as long as they are installed. My preference is the second one because it allows for optional (dev) dependencies.)

Comment: I switched the build-backend to hatchling and improved the answer accordingly. Hatchling does not create the annoying egg file.

Comment: You might want to try something like Pipenv if you only need something to manage the dependencies installed in the virtual environment but have no need for packaging and redistributing your project.

Comment: Thank you. pipenv does not seem to support pyproject.toml (and I don't use virtual environments.)

Comment: I see. `pip-tools` maybe then.

Comment: Hm. Why should I generate a requirements.txt from pyproject.toml and then install the requirements from requirements.txt ... if I am able to install them from pyproject.toml directly? I am afrait I still don't get the point.

Comment: There are use cases for something like `requirements.txt`. I do not know what your use case is. If you don't need any of this, then don't use it. I am not sure what you want to achieve. And I am not sure it really does relate to the original question. -- I guess it is fine if you do a slight misuse of `pyproject.toml` by using it only as a place to list dependencies that are easily installable with `pip install .`. It is unusual so others might be surprised, but it should work fine I think.

Comment: As stated above, I use it as central configuration file, including settings for pylint, pytest, black, etc. ... instead of using the old individual files having different formats ( .pylintrc, pytest.ini, ....). Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Although I want to do the same thing as this answer suggests, manually compiling a list of dependencies under `dev` is error-prone and certainly not any better than just having to maintain a `requirements.txt`. Not to mention, a dummy project name and version seems forced. Also, the GitHub ticket referenced here has been closed. Even though I appreciate the effort, I’m downvoting this answer so that other people don’t spend time reading it. Python simply isn’t ready for what this answer bends over backward to achieve.

Comment: I made the answer shorter so that is is less confusing. Also related: https://peps.python.org/pep-0665/  and https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/meta/faq/#libraries-vs-applications Therefore, I agree, that the standardization in Python is not ready, yet. I am still waiting for pyproject.toml to allow to specify both, fixed versions and version ranges. Nevertheless I find the above strategy a pragmatic solution for applications.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest switching to [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org), it's way better than a standard `pip` for dependency management. And because it uses `pyproject.toml` your dependencies and configs are in one place so it's easier to manage everything