# Specify dependencies in pyproject.toml with install URL or with index-url

Tags: python, dependencies, packaging, pyproject.toml

I like to have my package installable with `pip install ...` and to use the `pyproject.toml` standard.

I can specify dependencies to install from git, with:

```
dependencies = [
    'numpy>=1.21',
    'psychopy @ git+https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy',
]
```

But how can I specify a dependency to install from a different indexer, equivalent to:

`python -m pip install --pre --only-binary :all: -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scientific-python-nightly-wheels/simple numpy scipy`

With or without the pre-release flag?

And how can I specify a dependency to install from a URL, e.g. https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-22.04/wxPython-4.2.1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
I tried with no luck:

```
dependencies = [
    'wxPython @ https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-22.04/wxPython-4.2.1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl; python_version == "3.10"; sys_platform == "linux"'
]
```

Comment: it's insane. that file is now years old, all the tools as well, and still someone needs to ask that question. don't fear, @mathieu, you're not alone  . i came here with the same search, expecting a years old answer saying "oh, it's really simple, like this: ...". it reminds me that i hate loathe python packaging as much as i love the language. which is a _lot_.

Comment: You can't. It's been asked many times. I recommend you read the following article. It is outdated, but the principle of abstract dependencies vs. concrete dependencies is unchanged. Concrete dependencies do not belong in packaging metadata, i.e. concrete dependencies can not be added to the `project.dependencies` list in `pyproject.toml`. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading the article ["*`install_requires` vs. requirements files*" in the "*Python packaging user guide*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/).

This article is partly outdated but the principle of abstract dependencies vs. concrete dependencies is unchanged. Concrete dependencies do not belong in packaging metadata, i.e. concrete dependencies can not be added to the `dependencies` list in the `[project]` table of the `pyproject.toml` file.

As you have noted, it is possible to add ["*direct references*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#direct-references) (for example `psychopy @ git+https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy`), but not all packaging tools support this and notably *PyPI* rejects the upload of packages containing such dependencies.

What I often recommend, is that if there are dependencies that are not on *PyPI* then the documentation should reflect that very clearly and prominently. Where to get the dependencies and some examples of how to install them should be in the documentation, for example the URLs of the alternative package repositories.

And another thing that I recommend on top of the documentation is to provide one or more `requirements.txt` files that contain a list of concrete dependencies that have been tested and are known to work well. For example:

```
MyPackage
psychopy @ git+https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy
wxPython @ https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-22.04/wxPython-4.2.1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl; python_version == "3.10"; sys_platform == "linux"
```

And if I am not mistaken pip can install directly from the URL of such a requirements file: `python -m pip install --requirement https://host.example/my-package/requirements.txt` so such a command could be added to the documentation as well.

***Related***:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76548420

Answer (score 1):

using python 3.8.10

pip 23.3.1

im using a venv.

first install or update your dependencies.

```
$ python -m pip install --pre --only-binary :all: -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scientific-python-nightly-wheels/simple numpy scipy  
>> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.anaconda.org/scientific-python-nightly-wheels/simple
...
Successfully installed numpy-2.0.0.dev0 scipy-1.12.0.dev0
```

**git example**:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy                                                                                                                                        
>> Collecting git+https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy
...
Successfully built psychopy esprima future
Installing collected packages: pywin32, pytz, ...
```

**freeze all the dependencies:**

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

now all the *libraries* an *dependencies* for your project are listed in the **requirements.txt** file.

Assuming you're using SetupTools, I'll do the pyproject.toml:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "project"
version = "0.0.1"
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = "requirements.txt"}
```

That's all you need, the tests I did worked perfectly with what you ordered. I hope I was able to help you.