# Distributed package. Should it have requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm planning on developing a package for to be distributed on pypi and I can't find a clear answer for this question.

Should I add `requirements.txt` (or equivalent, like *.lock's) to the github repo?

I believe no. We add the requiments to pyproject.toml and then each one manages his environment if they want to contribute.

Right?

Thanks for earing me out.

I try reading documentation, but it's not clear as water.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [requirements.txt vs setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658870/requirements-txt-vs-setup-py)

Comment: And also [Is requirements.txt still needed when using pyproject.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74508024/4046632)

Comment: Are you working on a library or an application? In any case you can add `requirements.txt` (and/or a lockfile) to the source code repository without thinking too much about it. But for sure those files do not belong in the distributions (sdist and wheel).